# rails 4 merge 2 content for together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang, content-for

I have various pages that need multiple `content_for` at the top i.e:

```
- content_for :title, AppConfig.product['slogan']
- content_for :class, 'brand'
```

That are used in my layout:

```
== render 'layouts/top_wrapper'

  main[class="view-#{yield(:class)}-wrapper"]
    section[class="content-outer-wrapper"]
      div[class="row"]
        div[class="large-12"]
          div[class="content-inner-wrapper"]
            div[class="row"]
              div[class="large-12 large-centered columns text-center section-title"]
                h1
                  == yield(:title)
            div[class="row"]
              div[class="large-12 large-centered columns"]
                == yield

== render 'layouts/bottom_wrapper'
```

I was wondering if there is a way to merge them together into a single content_for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way. `content_for` stringifies your input so you cannot pass e.g. an array through that. You're still able to serialize your data though

```
- content_for :title_and_class, [AppConfig.product['slogan'], 'brand'].join(';')
- slogan, style = yield(:title_and_class).split(';')
```

but it is a little bit weird.

Comment: that's what I was thinking. thank you for the thorough reply, have a great weekend.